# How can I set a String variable on R.drawable with glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using the glide Library to load images and I made a method that goes like this:

```
void alterarInformacoes(ImageView slotImagem, String image) {
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.image)
                .into(slotImagem);
    }
```

But it doesn't work, I'd like to know if there's a way to use a string with the name of the drawable so that I can use a function to dynamically set the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get int value of drawable resource by name with this code:

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.